# Malformed multipart body error : uploading to google drive

Tags: file, upload, drive

I tried file uploading to the drive via API and got the response *'Malformed multipart body'*. (I tried to upload ipa and apk  files)

**Function used for upload is given below:**

```
def upload_file_drive(folder_id, access_token, path, name):


    para = {"name": name, "parents": [folder_id]}
    headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token}

    files = {'data': ('metadata', json.dumps(para), 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'), 'file': open(path, "rb")}
    response = requests.post("https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart", headers=headers, files=files)

    success_response = response.json()
    file_id = success_response['id']
    return file_id
```

This error is getting generated only for some files.

Comment: The error is with request body. You need to check your multipart form data.